# Dependent input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I want to have a dependent numeric input.

This numeric input depends on a select box that creates a specific numeric range for the input by selecting each option.

For example:

- if we select `option2`, the numeric input will be `min = 20` and `max = 50!`,
- if we select `option3`, the numeric input will be `min = 10` and `max = 30!`.

How can such a feature be created?

Here's what I've tried:

```
      <form>
    <select id="selbox">
      <option value="option1">option1</option>
      <option value="option2">option2</option>
     <option value="option3">option3</option>
</select>

   <input type="number" id="num">
<button>click</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to modify the min and max value of the number input.

```js
const num = document.querySelector("#num");
const selbox = document.querySelector("#selbox");

const range = {
  option1: [100, 120],
  option2: [20, 50],
  option3: [10, 30]
};

// Setting Initial Range Value
num.min = range['option1'][0];
num.max = range['option1'][1];

// Setting Range Value On Change
selbox.addEventListener("change", () => {
  num.min = range[selbox.value][0];
  num.max = range[selbox.value][1];
});
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="selbox">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
  </select>

  <input type="number" id="num">
  <button>click</button>
</form>
```